# Selenium moveToElement() to Selenide

Tags: java, selenium, selenide

I am starting with Selenide and would like to know if is possible to scroll to the element. In Seleniu the code looks like:

```
    Actions actions = new Actions(getWebDriver());
    actions.moveToElement(loadMore).build().perform();
```

I need to scroll to lement cause it is not clickable if it is outside the screen.

Comment: Most probably the selector is incorrect, check it in DevTools first.

Comment: No selector is ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selenide has `scrollIntoView` method, that implements JavaScript's `scrollIntoView` and scroll element to the specific position:

```
// the top of the element will be aligned to the top.
$("").scrollIntoView(true).click();

// element will be aligned to the center. 
$("").scrollIntoView("{behavior: \"instant\", block: \"center\", inline: \"center\"}").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this not suffice?

```
actions.moveToElement(loadMore).click().build().perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to click on an element even if it's outside the screen ( Make sure the XPath is correct!)
You can use actions.scrollIntoView(actions.findElement(By.xpath(xpath))

Comment: Are you sure? A lot of resources say it can be problem.

Comment: I've been using Selenium at my current work place for about half a year so I can't be 100% sure yet, but from my experience the browser will automatically scroll to the element if it's found when I try to click on it. I use driver.findElement(By.xapth(xpath)).click(); Note that before that I always put a driver.waitUntil(Expected condition.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath)), 20000) (20 seconds timeout ) to make sure the element is loaded/visible. Hope it helps! Let me know if you have any other questions!